# Hide KeyBoard Shortcuts Bar on a iOS Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

I am trying to build a custom keyboard for general use across many apps. I would like to hide the Keyboard Shortcuts Bar, but I am struggling to do this. All the posts on the forum that I have seen so far refer to using `inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()` or `inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []` with a textfield.

However, as I want to use this generally as opposed to just within my own app, I can't access a textfield.

I am trying to use it with the view as shown below, but obviously not working. I have tried so many variations now that I am completely confused.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "golfview", bundle: nil)
        let objects = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
        view = objects[0] as! UIView;

        //get rid of top bar of keyboard
        view.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
        view.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```

Comment: Are you referring to the suggestions bar which has copy / paste buttons etc ?

Comment: Yes. That’s correct.

Comment: Based on my experience that would be needed only for a `UITextField`. If you are setting a custom input view for a custom view other than a text field, just override `inputView` and return your custom input view. Try and build and see if it works for a `UIView` before building a generic solution

Comment: I’m new to iOS programming so your explanation is a good way above my knowledge level. Would you be able to give an example of how I could achieve that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Creating a custom input view for a custom view

#### Approach:

- Create a Green input view
- Create a Red view
- When the red view becomes the first responder the green view should show

## Code:

#### Green Input View:

```
import UIKit

class GreenInputView : UIView {

    //MARK: Initializers

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    //MARK: Setup

    private func setup() {

        backgroundColor = .green

        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    }
}
```

#### Red View:

```
import UIKit

class RedView : UIView {

    private let greenInputView = GreenInputView()

    //MARK: Initializers

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    //MARK: Setup

    private func setup() {

        setupBase()
        setupGreenInputView()
    }

    private func setupBase() {

        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    private func setupGreenInputView() {
        greenInputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputView: UIView? {
        return greenInputView
    }
}
```

#### ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let redView = RedView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupRedView()
    }

    private func setupRedView() {

        view.addSubview(redView)

        redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        redView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        redView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

## Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of green input view]